# How to configure the DNS record for a domain name to point both at the same IP address?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns, url-rewrite-module

My website behaves differently with http://example.com and http://www.example.com. I know these are considered as two different domains. But what do I do to fix this issue? People will mostly type example.com instead of the full url, therefore what should I do so that the two urls' point to the same website?

Answer (score 0):

- First thing that you need to do is to make sure that DNS server has records for both of those domains pointing to the same server (A records).
- You need to add bindings for those two addresses to point to the same web application in the web server settings (In case of IIS you will need to add multiple bindings on *Edit Site* menu)
- In case you need to redirect HTTP to HTTPS you can use IIS rewrite module with the following rule

Rule

```
<rule name="RedirectToWWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*your-domain\.com" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="www\.your-domain\.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.your-domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: Both the domains are pointing to the same ip address in DNS. It seems my code is considering the two domains differently.

Comment: Is there a way to redirect the user to www.example.com in case the person types example.com.

Comment: Yes, that is the rule I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: That rule is to redirect from http to https. I need to redirect from example.com to www.example.com. I'll try to edit it to but where should I place this rule? Should it be placed on all pages on the server? How to go about it?

Comment: You can change that rule a bit and get that redirect. If you can't I'll try to give you updated rule in few moments

Comment: I've more doubts. Where should I place this rule tag? I'm using php and js. Also I'm using session variables. When I change from www.example.com to example.com or vice-versa, session variables will be impacted.  Maybe session variables are causing my website to behave differently when moving from one domain to another.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, did you had asp.net tag on the question and switched it to php ? on ... never mind ... please refer to the following - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html